# Nodemon doesn't reload in docker container when files change

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nodemon

I read many threads sabout this but no one solves anything.

Some say you have to add `--legacy-watch` (or `-L`) to the `nodemon` command.
Others shows several different configurations and apparently nodody really knows what you gotta do to achieve server restarting when a file change at the volume inside a docker container.

Here my configuration so far:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install nodemon globally
RUN npm install nodemon -g

# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Exports
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    node:
        build: .
        user: "node"
        volumes:
        - ./:/usr/src/app
        ports: 
            - 3000:3000
        depends_on: 
            - mongo
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        environment:
        - NODE_ENV=production
        expose:
        - "3000"
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        expose:
        - 27017
        volumes:
        - ./data/db:/data/db
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-playground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon -L"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
  }
}
```

I tried many different setups as well. Like not installing globally `nodemon` but only as a project dependency. And also running the command at the `docker-compse.yml`, and i believe many others I don't remember right now. Nothing.

If someone has any cetainty about this, please help. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Are you calling `nodemon` in your `NPM` script? aka does `npm start` contain the `nodemon` command? Can you supply your `package.json`? I don't see where you are even running the `nodemon` command...

Comment: @MattOestreich so sorry, I forgot about that file. Edited.

Comment: You run the container as user `node`, while you also supply a volume that is owned by whatever user owns them in the host system. Are you sure you have the right permissions?

Comment: So is your container even starting? Is the app inside of your container responsive? Meaning, `nodemon` starts your app, it just doesn't reload when something changes?

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski I'll try removing the user reference.

Comment: @MattOestreich yes, tha application starts, it just doens't reload at file changes, so you don't see these at the browser.

Comment: and which files are changing exactly? You're sure the files that are changing live inside of the container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went ahead and created an example container and repo to show how you can achieve this..

Just follow the steps below, which outline how to use `nodemon` inside of a `Docker` container.

---

**Docker Container:** [at DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/oze4/nodemon-docker-test)

**Source Code:** [at GitHub](https://github.com/oze4/nodemon-docker-test)

---

***package.json:***

```
{
  "name": "nodemon-docker-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:express": "node ./index.js",
    "start": "nodemon"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
  }
}
```

---

***Dockerfile:***

```
FROM node:slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN apt-get update
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
# -or-
# COPY . .
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

---

***docker-compose.yml:*** (if you are using it)

```
version: "3"
services:
  nodemon-test:
    image: oze4/nodemon-docker-test
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
```

---

***How to reproduce:***

*Step 1 **USING DOCKER RUN**:* SKIP IF YOU ARE USING DOCKER COMPOSE (go to step 1 below if you are) pull down example docker container

`docker run -d --name "nodemon-test" -p 1337:1337 oze4/nodemon-docker-test`

[image]

---

*Step 1 **USING DOCKER-COMPOSE**:*

See the `docker-compose.yml` file above for configuration

1. `cd /path/to/dir/that/has/your/compose/file`
2. `docker-compose up -d`

[image]

---

*Step 2:* verify the app works

http://localhost:1337

[image]

---

*Step 3:* check the container logs, to get a baseline

`docker logs nodemon-test`

[image]

---

*Step 4:* I have included a `bash` script to make editing a file as simple as possible. We need to pop a shell on the container, and run the `bash` script (`change.sh`)

1. `docker exec -it nodemon-test /bin/bash`
2. `bash change.sh`
3. `exit`

[image]

---

*Step 5:* check the logs again to verify changes were made and that `nodemon` restarted

`docker logs nodemon-test`

[image]

---

---

As you can see by the last screenshot, `nodemon` successfully restarted after changes were made!

---

---

Comment: Uau thanks a lot for your instructions!! i'll tried them when i get back from work

Comment: One thought about your example is that I need to achive ths using docker-compose.

Comment: @MarcosDiPaolo my bad... I went ahead and added a step that outlines how to accomplish this using `docker-compose`... I also updated the GitHub Repo with the .yml file... Cheers!!

Comment: Is it necessary to change the files through `docker exec` ? Or can you normally code it throug VSCode and changes will be reflected?

Comment: Hi. Tks for the answer @MattOestreich. Can you outline what was the change you made that did it? I was comparing the equation files and what called my attention were the "node:slim" and the "apt-get" in Dockefile. Is any of those commands that made the difference?

Answer (score 27):

Try it!
This worked for me:

Via the CLI, use either `--legacy-watch` or `-L` for short. More informations [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting).

Comment: Holy sh*t... my code was right! And I was just missing that flag.

Comment: Other packages have similar flags, for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload has the "--usepolling" to activate this behavior. The underlying implementation that uses these flags is https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar

Comment: Firstly thanks, it worked for me, but it's too slow and the host doesn't reload the web tab itself, i have to do it manually. Is this a normal behavior, new in docker.

Answer (score 4):

All right
Thanks a lot to MattOestreich for your answer.
Now i got it working, I don't know what it was, i did follow your set up but of course i'm using docker-compose and i also stripped some things out of it. I'm also not calling mongo image anymore since i setup the db in an Mongodb atlas cluster. 
my actual config:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN apt-get update

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compse.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    node:
        build: .
        volumes:
        - ./:/app
        ports: 
            - 3000:3000
        working_dir: /app
        expose:
        - "3000"
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-playground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "ejs": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
  }
}
```

thanks Matt again and i hope this thread helps people in need like me.

Answer (score 4):

Nodemon depends on [Chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/1051) and a potential solution is to make it use polling by setting `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` environment variable to `true`.

For example you can do this in docker-compose.yml:

```
services: 
    api1:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ${PWD}:/app
        ports:
            - 80:3000
        environment:
            - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Answer (score 3):

Change in Docker file

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Change start script

```
"start": "nodemon -L server.js"
```

Build Command

```
docker build . -t <containername>
```

Use this command to run the docker container

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/app -p 8080:8080 -it <container Id>
```

- -v = Volumes . the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers.
- /app = WORKDIR /app
- $(pwd) = PWD is a variable set to the present working directory. So $(pwd) gets the value of the present working directory