# Mounted directory empty with docker-compose and custom Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am very (read very) new to Docker so experimenting. I have created a very basic Dockerfile to pull in Laravel:

```
FROM composer:latest
RUN composer_version="$(composer --version)" && echo $composer_version
RUN composer global require laravel/installer
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel site
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

    laravel:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: laravel.dockerfile
        container_name: my_laravel
        network_mode: host
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
            - ./site:/var/www/site
```

When I run docker-compose up, the ./site directory is created but the contents are empty. I've put this in docker-compose as I plan on on including other things like nginx, mysql, php etc

The command:

```
docker run -v "/where/i/want/data/site:/var/www/site" my_laravel
```

Results in the same behaviour.

I know the install is successful as I modified my dockerfile with the follwing two lines appended to it:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/site
RUN ls -la
```

Which gives me the correct listing.

Clearly misunderstanding something here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** So, I was able to get this to work... although, it slightly more difficult than just specifying a path..

You can accomplish this by specifying a volume in `docker-compose.yml`.. The path to the directory (on the host) is labeled as `device` in the compose file.. It appears that the root of the path has to be an actual volume (possibly a share would work) but the 'destination' of the path can be a directory on the specified volume..

I created a new volume called `docker` on my machine but I suppose you could do this with your existing disk/volume..

***I am on a Mac and this `docker-compose.yml` file worked for me:***

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nodemon-test:
    container_name: my-nodemon-test
    image: oze4/nodemon-docker-test
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    volumes:
      - docker_test_app:/app    # see comment below on which name to use here

volumes:
  docker_test_app:              # use this name under `volumes:` for the service
    name: docker_test_app
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       o: bind
       type: none
       device: /Volumes/docker/docker_test_app
```

The container specified exists in my DockerHub.. [this is the source code](https://github.com/oze4/nodemon-docker-test) for it, just in case you are worried about anything malicious. I created it like two weeks ago to [help someone else on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946095/nodemon-doesnt-reload-in-docker-container-when-files-change/57948076#57948076).

---

***Shows files from the container on my machine (the host)..***

[image]

---

You can read more about Docker Volume configs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) if you would like.

---

***ORIGINAL ANSWER:***

It looks like you are trying to share the build directory with your host machine.. After some testing, it appears Docker will overwrite the specified path on the container with the contents of the path on the host.

If you run `docker logs my_laravel` you should see an error about missing files at `/var/www/site`.. So, even though the build is successful - once Docker mounts the directory from your machine (`./site`) onto the container (`/var/www/site`) it overwrites the path within the container (`/var/www/site`) with the contents of the path on your host (`./site`) - which is empty.

To test and make sure the contents of `/var/www/site` are in fact being overwritten, you can run `docker exec -it /bin/bash` (you may need to replace `/bin/bash` with `/bash`).. This will give you command line access *inside* of the container. From there you can do `ls -a /var/www/site`..

Furthermore, you can also pre-stage `./site` to have a random test file in it (`test.txt` or whatever), then `docker-compose up -d`, then run the same commands from the step above `docker exec -it ...` and see if the staged `test.txt` file is now inside the container - this gives you definitive evidence that when you run `volumes`, the data on your host overwrites data in the container.

With that being said, [doing something like this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host#step-1-%E2%80%94-bindmounting-a-volume) and sharing a log directory will work... the volume path specified on the container is still overwritten, the difference is the container is writing to that path.. it doesn't rely on it for config files/app files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are quite right. Any volumes I define will be pulled into the container and thus overwrite anything in there. I'm looking at a different way using CMD to accomplish what I want i.e. - populating the bound directory when the container is first invoked.

Comment: @Zakalwe I figured out how to accomplish this - I have updated my answer with an explanation on how I did it.

Comment: This is great thank you! Just need to tidy up some Laravel-specific permissions but this did the trick, Thanks for looking into this.